# Types/Conversion error attempting to build C++ .DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I found the following snippet of code and am trying to create an ISAPI .DLL using it.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <httpfilt.h>
#include "tchar.h"
#include "strsafe.h"

// Portion of HttpOnly
DWORD WINAPI HttpFilterProc(
   PHTTP_FILTER_CONTEXT pfc,
   DWORD dwNotificationType,
   LPVOID pvNotification) {

   // Hard coded cookie length (2k bytes)
   CHAR szCookie[2048];
   DWORD cbCookieOriginal = sizeof(szCookie) / sizeof(szCookie[0]);
   DWORD cbCookie = cbCookieOriginal;

      HTTP_FILTER_SEND_RESPONSE *pResponse = 
         (HTTP_FILTER_SEND_RESPONSE*)pvNotification;

      CHAR *szHeader = "Set-Cookie:";
      CHAR *szHttpOnly = "; HttpOnly";
      if (pResponse->GetHeader(pfc,szHeader,szCookie,&cbCookie)) {
         if (SUCCEEDED(StringCchCat(szCookie,
                                    cbCookieOriginal,
                                    szHttpOnly))) {
            if (!pResponse->SetHeader(pfc,
                                      szHeader,
                                      szCookie)) {
                        // Fail securely - send no cookie!
                        pResponse->SetHeader(pfc,szHeader,"");
               }
            } else {
               pResponse->SetHeader(pfc,szHeader,"");
          }
   }

   return SF_STATUS_REQ_NEXT_NOTIFICATION;
}
```

I created a new C++ project using VS 2010 Express. I get the following error when I build the project:

```
------ Build started: Project: ISAPIHttpOnly, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  HttpOnly.cpp
c:\documents and settings\bob\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\isapihttponly\isapihttponly\httponly.cpp(25): error C2664: 'StringCchCatW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CHAR [2048]' to 'STRSAFE_LPWSTR'
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this. :S

Comment: Your program is compiling as Unicode, try changing `CHAR` to `TCHAR`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean to change all CHAR to TCHAR or not. I tried that and it generated about 10 errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is being compiled as Unicode, then `STRSAFE_LPWSTR`, which is the type from the first parameter in `StringCchCat`, is failing against an `char` array type, which is not Unicode.

To solve this, you have two choices, one is to declare the erroneous string as an `TCHAR` array, so it can be preprocessed to an `wchar_t` array. But then you'd have to change a lot of things in your code, like literal trings would need the `TEXT("")` macro, etc.

But as it seems, your program was not done to use Unicode strings, so the other choice is to compile your program as Multi-Byte, then you don't need to change anything in your code because `StringCchCat` will have a `STRSAFE_LPSTR` parameter, which will be preprocessed to `char *`.

To compile as Multi-Byte, just go to <kbd>Project Settings</kbd>-><kbd>General</kbd>-><kbd>Character Set</kbd>.

Comment: I changed the Character Set to Mulyi-Byte and it built with no errors. Thank you!